# How to use different method of a controller in laravel application

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, controller

In my laravel application i should use some create and update method of some controller in another controller

According to my search is not a good thing to call a method from controller in another

I cant see the why don't call a controller method in another controller

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing this way :

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    protected $variable;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->variable = "Hello";
    }
}
```

and

```
class ClientController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Comment: i cant use this way because like this i should extend from 4 other controller

Comment: The constructor is bound to a class. It sounds like you want to use the same function in different classes. Maybe you should look into traits?

Comment: i use triat but the method name in trait can not be __constructor bcause in my controller __constructor would be overwritten

Answer (score 2):

The `__constructor` is a magic method of class. It calls when you trying to create instance of class. So there is no way to use `constructor` without creating an instance or extendeding from another class. If you have a common code in different classes there a best way to use `traits`. thats give you an opportunity to include your trait and use methods ,making your code beutiful , flexible , readable following principes `DRY`,`KISS`.

Answer (score 1):

> you can create a base class with constructor and extend other controller of it
>
> or you can put your code in to  Http\Controllers\controller.php ('main controllers constructor')
>
> also you can use trait